# Python hit 'submit' button on web form, how I find out what gets sent to the website AND how its sent?

Tags: python-3.x

The title of the post pretty much says it all.  I fill a one box form and hit the submit button and get back the results from the website.  I need to find out what/how the text box data goes to the website.  How do I find out what gets sent AND how its sent?  I want to be able to 'autofill' in the form and submit it but I don't know how to do it.

I can bring up the headers but, yeah, I'm a little lost in what/how they behave.  I tried a simple program a couple of days ago but I couldn't tell what happened with the program...was it actually submitting anything or not.  I don't know how to test it since I'm not using a browser for making the call.

```
import requests
import json
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

URL = 'https://us.hidester.com/do.php?action=go'

data = {'langsel':'en','u':'https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/cgi-bin/data/composites/comp.day.pl?var=Geopotential+Height&level=1000mb&monr1=1&dayr1=1&monr2=1&dayr2=1&iyr[1]=2018&filenamein=&type=1&proj=ALL','encodeURL':'on','allowCookies':'on','stripJS':'on'}
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0'}
resp = requests.get(URL, params=data, headers=headers)
```

I did the above a couple of days ago and when I went and tried

```
print(resp)
```

All I got back was

```
Response [200]
```

Whatever that means.

How do I go about getting what the webpage returns to me, aka another webpage when that webpage is all dependent on what I sent it initially, and that gets encrypted.

Yeah, I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome developer tools to find what is the post request and what form data and header is posted when you click the button. 
After which you can build your python code to perform the form post with the required data and check the response.

to check what is the response you can add code `print (resp.content)` to print the response to your request

Comment: I updated my question with what I did a couple of days ago and the response I was getting back..Response 200.  I'm not sure where to go from that point though.

Comment: didn't that help you?